# OpenCV linux how to install FFMPEG

Tags: java, linux, opencv, ubuntu, ffmpeg

Can someone please help me with a working method on how to install `FFMPEG` on linux, I have followed several tutorials and they seem to work except after everything `FFMPEG` is never found in the system, even after several system reboots my last try was from this link [Compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu, Debian, or Mint](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)

I did everything in the tutorial but when i run the `man ffmpeg` it tells me no manual found and `OpenCV` too does not detect it, I tried calling the `Core.getBuildInformation()` and the output was:

```
GUI: 
QT:                          NO
GTK+:                        NO
GThread :                    NO
GtkGlExt:                    NO
OpenGL support:              NO
VTK support:                 NO

Media I/O: 
ZLib:                        zlib (ver 1.2.8)
JPEG:                        libjpeg (ver 90)
WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.24)
TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
GDAL:                        NO
GDCM:                        NO

Video I/O:
DC1394 1.x:                  NO
DC1394 2.x:                  NO
FFMPEG:                      NO
  avcodec:                   NO
  avformat:                  NO
  avutil:                    NO
  swscale:                   NO
  avresample:                NO
GStreamer:                   NO
OpenNI:                      NO
OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
OpenNI2:                     NO
PvAPI:                       NO
GigEVisionSDK:               NO
Aravis SDK:                  NO
UniCap:                      NO
UniCap ucil:                 NO
V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
XIMEA:                       NO
Xine:                        NO
gPhoto2:                     NO

Parallel framework:            pthreads

Other third-party libraries:
Use IPP:                     9.0.1 [9.0.1]
     at:                     /home/daddy/opencv-3.2.0/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
Use IPP Async:               NO
Use VA:                      NO
Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
Use Lapack:                  NO
Use Eigen:                   NO
Use Cuda:                    NO
Use OpenCL:                  YES
Use OpenVX:                  NO
Use custom HAL:              NO

OpenCL:                        <Dynamic loading of OpenCL library>
Include path:                /home/daddy/opencv-3.2.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
Use AMDFFT:                  NO
Use AMDBLAS:                 NO

Python 2:
Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.12)

Python 3:
Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.2)

Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7

Java:
ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.9.6)
JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include
Java wrappers:               YES
Java tests:                  YES

Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled

Documentation:
Doxygen:                     NO

Tests and samples:
Tests:                       YES
Performance tests:           YES
C/C++ Examples:              NO

Install path:                  /usr/loca
cvconfig.h is in:              /home/user/opencv-3.2.0/build
```

Answer (score 2):

On `.deb` systems, you need to install *libavformat-dev, libavcodec-dev, libswscale-dev, libavresample-dev packages.

Comment: it still cant detect `FFMPEG`

Comment: Could you try deleting the build folder and rerunning the cmake? Theese might have ffmpeg versions, like libavformat-ffmpeg-dev, etc. you may also like to install them.

Comment: well, let me try that again

Comment: Confirmed, with Ubuntu 18, installing `ffmpeg` package alone didn't work, but adding these four with (`sudo apt install`) and clearing the build folder did well.

Answer (score 1):

Use docker Image which has everything pre-configured if you can. Makes your life so much easier ---  [Docker Image](https://github.com/ampervue/docker-python34-opencv3)